# How do you get an html element to move to a random spot using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    #myDIV {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: coral;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Click the "Try it" button to position the DIV element 100 pixels from 
    the 
    right edge:</p>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> If the position property is set to "static", the 
    right 
    property has no effect.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <div id="myDIV">
     <h1>myDIV</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.right = Math.floor(Math.random() 
    * 1) 
    + 100.px  ;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But it still doesn't work! I haven't tried much though.

Comment: you need to add the unit `px` (for example)

Comment: This will never execute as you have it inside the double quotes - `"Math.floor(Math.random() 
* 1) + 100  ";`

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: thx I will try!

Comment: :( I couldn't get it to work...

Comment: This is my new code:

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Sorry, but it does not work!

Comment: and @Mr.Alien!!

Answer (score 3):

### A Basic Solution

This will place the `div` to a random spot anywhere (x/y) in the viewport. I added a `transition` to make things a little smoother.

[image]

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const box = document.getElementById("myDIV");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let randY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
  let randX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  box.style.top = randY + "px";
  box.style.right = randX + "px";
});
```

```css
#myDIV {
  --div-width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  transition: .5s top, .5s right;
  top: 0;  
  right: calc(100% - var(--div-width));
  width: var(--div-width);
}

button {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button>Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oghbw8nv/7/)

### A Better Solution

Animating `top` and `left`/`right` are not very performant and should be replaced by `transform`s. Using a `transform` to move things around activates hardware acceleration. The system will use its GPU to do the animation which will be as smooth as native app performance. If you're making a game as you've mentioned, you will want to make it app-like in a mobile environment.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button");
const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
const width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
const box = document.getElementById("myDIV");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let randY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
  let randX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
  box.style.transform = `translate(${randX}px, ${randY}px)`;
});
```

```css
#myDIV {
  --div-width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s transform;
  top: 0;  
  width: var(--div-width);
}

button {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button>Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vou7016/)

Comment: This is cool but i've made it into a cool game very fast. I've added transitions and thx for the random x and y !! I shall implement this into the game!

Comment: I've also added a reset button that uses window.location.reload():    <input type="button" value="RESET" onclick="window.location.reload" />

Comment: As of again, thank you! this has improved my game lots. I never knew that u could have const as a constant!

Comment: @I.M.Smart If you’re happy with my answer, I’d be grateful if you could select it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost correct. Just need a little bit of changes in JS.
Check you my solution. Hope this helps!

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.right = Math.random() * window.innerWidth + 'px';
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to position the DIV element a random amount of 
pixels from the 
right edge:</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> If the position property is set to "static", the 
right property has no effect.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I use this for a css property called filter and I use invert with it!! Hopefully when i hover over it it will turn a inverted colour!

Comment: I will have a black box, with a black background, and you will need to hover over the box (or circle) to reveal it!!

Comment: Could U please make it into html form so I can copy-paste it into my editor!                      That will help!

Comment: If you need a picture on your tabs, use this snippet of code in your head;

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> but don't use favicon.ico, use your picture(in a .ico format)

Comment: **NOTE:** I have made it so you need to click on the div to move it! Please, if you are going to give any more answers, make sure you click on the box, not a button...

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    #myDIV {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to position the DIV element a random amount of 
pixels from the 
right edge:</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> If the position property is set to "static", the 
right property has no effect.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.right = Math.floor(Math.random()*(1000-0+1)+0)+"px";  ;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.right = Math.random() * window.innerWidth 
+ 
'px';
}
</script>
<style>
#myDIV {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the "Try it" button to position the DIV element a random amount of 
pixels from the 
right edge:</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> If the position property is set to "static", the 
right property has no effect.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has been a lot of help to me. Thanks to everyone who supported it. I will change the css and hopefully make it into what could become a game!